# PHP calling MySQL insert stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

We are new to using the stored procedures in MySQL and have created a test stored procedure which simply adds a name to the database.
We have tested it in MySql and it worked fine but we are having problems getting it to work from PHP. We have the following code and when we run it we get the message "Done" but the record has not been added

```
include 'Header.php'; <<< sets up access to DB
$name = "Richard";
$result = mysql_query("CALL SPTestInsert('$name')");
echo "Done";
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks
Rich

Comment: Check for errors by adding `or die(mysql_error())` after the `mysql_query()` call.

Comment: May you show the procedure too.

Comment: That code looks okay, but we don't know how you set it up. Also, that looks really prone to SQL injection attacks...

Comment: If this approach is open to SQL injection what would be the best approach to take.